# Error while extracting lemma from a sentence using stanford core NLP for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying [stanford nlp](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Stanford.NLP) in .NET . I want to extract Lemma from given sentences. When I execute this code I'm running into the following error. 
*Unable to open *"edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as class path, filename or URL*.

> Can anyone please tell me where will I get that file and where should
>   I place that file.?

I have added the sample code..

```
               var text = "what is humidity";
                var doc = new edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Document(text);
                var sentences = doc.sentences().toArray();

                foreach (edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Sentence sent in sentences)
                {
                    var temp = sent.lemma(2); //getting error here
                }
```

Comment: Have you installed the [POS Tagger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stanford.NLP.POSTagger/) as well?

Comment: I tried after installed , but getting the same error

Comment: You might need to [raise an issue with them](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues)